# Replacing column values based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a huge tabledb with 1.6M entries. I want to replace

```
SELECT `Type` FROM `my_db` WHERE `Type` != "a" AND `Type` != "b" AND `Type` != "c"
```

The above query gives me close to 7K rows.

I want to Update all the selected row's through the above query to have `Type` reassigned to value `"a"`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an `update`:

```
update mydb
    set type = 'a'
    where type not in ('a', 'b', 'c');
```